# Why is RSpec is throwing an error despite the diff between the expected and received value being nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I get the following RSpec error sporadically and am confused as to what it is:

```
Failure/Error: Question.all[index].created_at.should == sorted_publish_dates[index]
       expected: Tue, 02 Aug 2011 21:11:11 UTC +00:00
            got: Tue, 02 Aug 2011 21:11:11 UTC +00:00 (using ==)
       Diff:
     # ./spec/models/question_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The expected and received values appear to be exactly the same so I'm confused as to why RSpec thinks it's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see what those time values actually are, convert them to floats via to_f before asking rspec to compare them.

Or, for a more readable value, call time.xmlschema(6) which will display microsecond precision.

You may want to rethink how you're generating these values for the test and in your app. In your app, are the 2 time values guaranteed to be the same, down to the microsecond? If so, does your test generate the times the same way?

Comment: They should the the same as one was the source for setting the other. I think I've solved the problem though by comparing the .to_s (rather than .to_f) values of each. Since they differ by at least hours it does the job just right - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are testing against Time.now (I suspect).   Even though rspec is showing the same time string it isn't including milliseconds in the output.   You will need to stub Time.now when you setup the test so that you can reliably measure that your are in fact testing for the same time as the object creation.

```
before do
  Time.stub!(:now).and_return("2011-02-08 21:11:11")
end
```

Comment: I think it's actually to do with some peculiarities of things going in and out of the database because it's checking the defined value that an item was set with against the read-value of it (it's checking sort order). With your help though I addressed the problem by comparing the .to_s values instead of the actual values therefore dropping the ms.

Answer (score 0):

The to_s for your items are the same. That does not mean that the items are the same. I bet that they are instances of different classes.

Comment: They're definitely the same class and the error is only sporadic - most of the time it passes. Different classes would indicate a consistent error